# Ag-Grid paginationGoToPage not working (Server-Side Row Model / Infinite Scroll)

Tags: pagination, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am currently working on implementing Ag-Grid in React such that it is able to take in query parameters from a URL string and spit out specified filtering, sorting, and pagination behavior. Here is the code that takes in the query parameters and instructs Ag-Grid to display data based on those params:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (gridRef?.current.api) {
      gridRef.current.api.setServerSideDatasource(datasource)
    }
  }, [gridRef, datasource, watchedValues])

  const onGridReady = event => {
    const { api, columnApi } = event

    api.setServerSideDatasource(datasource)

    if (initialParams && initialParams.filterModel) {
      api.setFilterModel(initialParams.filterModel)
    }

    if (initialParams && initialParams.sortModel) {
      columnApi.applyColumnState({
        state: initialParams.sortModel,
        defaultState: { sort: null },
      })
    }

    if (initialParams && initialParams.startRow) {
      api.paginationGoToPage(Math.floor(initialParams.startRow / 50))
    }

    if (sizeToFit) {
      api.sizeColumnsToFit()
    }
  }
```

Everything in this code block works beautifully EXCEPT for `api.paginationGoToPage`. We've even tried hardcoding values in just to see if we could make it go to ANY page, but to no avail. The rest of the api functions are working, why is this one not doing anything?

As mentioned above, we tried hardcoding values into the function just to see if we could get it to do anything. I have tried moving pagination handling into the server-side datasource function, but what ends up happening is that the grid will display the page we want, but the pagination will still show that we are at page one (and will be stuck on that page of data since we're using url params, which are not changing, to dictate what page we are on). The grid definitely seems to need to be instructed to go to a particular page if it is to sync up with its own pagination, but the method used to do that is simply not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone runs into this issue, the grid needs to actually render before it can be instructed to go to a particular page.

I ended up creating an `onFirstDataRendered` method:

```
const onFirstDataRendered = event => {
    const { api } = event

    if (initialParams && initialParams.startRow) {
      api.paginationGoToPage(Math.floor(initialParams.startRow / 50))
    }
  }
```

The method is fed to the grid instance: `onFirstDataRendered={onFirstDataRendered}`

This worked. Unfortunately it requires to api calls, but this was the best solution I was able to create after speaking with an Ag-Grid developer.